# How to add 3 decimal places Currency formatting to edittext Using TextWatcher Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, number-formatting, android-textwatcher

I want to add **3 decimal places** **currency formatting** to *EditText* using *TextWatcher* 
at the beginning, value is **0.000** and the number should **change right to left**

eg: if I pressed 1,2,3,4,5 in order value should appear as this **12.345**

following code is worked only for 2 decimal places. Please anyone helps me ***how to change this code for 3 decimal places*** or another solution

```
 public class CurrencyTextWatcher  implements TextWatcher {
    boolean mEditing;
    Context context;


    public CurrencyTextWatcher() {
        mEditing = false;
    }

    public synchronized void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        if(!mEditing) {
            mEditing = true;
            String digits = s.toString().replaceAll("\\D", "");
             NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

            try{
                String formatted = nf.format(Double.parseDouble(digits)/100);
                s.replace(0, s.length(), formatted);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                s.clear();
            }
            mEditing = false;
        }
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide 1000 instead of 100 and also `setMinimumFractionDigits` for `NumberFormat` as 3.

```
public class CurrencyTextWatcher  implements TextWatcher {
    boolean mEditing;
    Context context;


    public CurrencyTextWatcher() {
        mEditing = false;
    }

    public synchronized void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        if(!mEditing) {
            mEditing = true;
            String digits = s.toString().replaceAll("\\D", "");
            NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
            nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);

            try{
                String formatted = nf.format(Double.parseDouble(digits)/1000);
                s.replace(0, s.length(), formatted);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                s.clear();
            }
            mEditing = false;
        }
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }

}
```

Comment: when divided by 1000 still it  shows 2 decimal places in edittext and input change not work  as aspect